# Limit Salesforce objects and fields in Tableau Desktop

Tags: tableau

In connecting Salesforce to Tableau Desktop it brings in every single object as a table. Within each table/object it brings in every single field. The issue is there are many standard objects my org doesn't use. Within each object there are even more fields which we don't need.

Is there a way when connecting Salesforce to Tableau Desktop to do data analysis to only show certain objects/tables, and within those, pick which fields to display.

My hope is to have a setup for all the analysts on my team to just open up Tableau Desktop, connect to our Salesforce instance, and just see the tables (and fields within those tables) that are relevant for analysis and not every single object and field.

Comment: [Custom connection](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/examples_salesforce.htm) (under the SF connector-based data source) will do this. Another option for filtering is to use Prep + custom SQL for SF connector, this is new in [Prep 2022.1.1](https://help.tableau.com/current/prep/en-us/prep_whatsnew.htm#connect-to-data). Last but not least, the standard option - you can pull all objects and then analyze only a subset in a workbook/site/etc.

Comment: Thanks @identigral, are there any examples of a custom Salesforce tdc. I'm having a hard time knowing where to start and having an example to work off of would be super helpful